# How to acomplish the Google Phone stay on top effect html?

Tags: html, css, dhtml

Google phone opens up a small widget on the right of Gmail and stays there. Even when navigating to other emails or composing at email (similar effect is achieved I believe by Facebook chat).

Are they using frames? I hope not.

I need to keep some images open while the user navigates other parts of the application so using the approach of google to place my image holders would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with google phone, but maybe an iframe is what you are after:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

It's an inline reference to another document.

Comment: They don't use iframes.. I already check...   Using Iframe would work, but then I would be actually using iframes... which I want to stay away from.

Comment: If you want to avoid using iframes, how about a simple div with position:static?